# How to Extract data between two lines in python scrpit

Tags: python, regex

i want to extract data between two lines i have text files that have different pattern i have python code that is working for numbers but not working for text so i want help

My text file format 1

> TAX INVOICE (Under Rule 46 of the Central Goods & Service Tax Rules, 2017)
> ANURAG ENTERPRISES ANURAG ENTERPRISES, VEDAVATHI NAGAR,CHALLAKERE ROAD HIRIYUR 
> State Code: 29

My text file format 2

> Page 1 of 1
> KS LINGAPPA AND SON Industrial Area, Plot No 14. KSSIDC TBDam Road, Hosapete-583201 State Karnataka
> State Code 29

Output that i want

> 1.ANURAG ENTERPRISES ANURAG ENTERPRISES
> 2.KS LINGAPPA AND SON

```
for name in files:
with open(name, encoding="utf8") as infile:
 copy = False
 cnt=0
 for line in infile: 
        
           if line.strip()=="Page":
                 copy = True
                 continue
           if line.strip()=="TAX":
                 copy = True
                 continue
           elif line.strip() == "State":
                  copy = False
                  continue

           elif copy:
                 print(line)
```

Comment: from the example, it's not clear what the extraction rules are - can you formalize them and update the question?
Also, the indentation of your example code is off - it will not run!

Answer (score 0):

As Onno Rouast commented, it is not very clear what the extraction rules are. The following works with the two examples provided, but who can tell what the future will bring?

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ma0ED/1/)

```
import re

rex = r"""(?xm)         # extended mode and multiline
(?:^(?:Page|TAX).*\n)   # preceded by a line starting with either Page or TAX
\b([A-Z ]+)\b           # Looking for all capital letters or spaces"""

text = """TAX INVOICE (Under Rule 46 of the Central Goods & Service Tax Rules, 2017)
ANURAG ENTERPRISES ANURAG ENTERPRISES, VEDAVATHI NAGAR,CHALLAKERE ROAD HIRIYUR
State Code: 29

Page 1 of 1
KS LINGAPPA AND SON Industrial Area, Plot No 14. KSSIDC TBDam Road, Hosapete-583201 State Karnataka
State Code 29"""

companies = [s.strip() for s in re.findall(rex, text)]
print(companies)
```

Prints:

```
['ANURAG ENTERPRISES ANURAG ENTERPRISES', 'KS LINGAPPA AND SON']
```

**Update**

```
import re

rex = r"""(?xm)         # extended mode and multiline
(?:^(?:Page|TAX).*\n)   # preceded by a line starting with either Page or TAX
\b([A-Z ]+)\b           # Looking for all capital letters or spaces"""

files = ['name1', name2', 'etc.']
all_companies = []
for name in files:
    with open(name, encoding="utf8") as infile:
        text = infile.read()
        # in case there can be multiple occurences in each file (it's not clear):
        companies = [s.strip() for s in re.findall(rex, text)]
        print(companies)
        all_companies.extend(companies) # list of all companies found in all files
```

Comment: Hi @Booboo can you tell me how and where i can use your code in my code because i am using text file by with open function